# Populating Drop Down List from Previous Drop Down - using AJAX, PDO, jQuery

Tags: mysql

I'm brand new to using PHP and mySQL so I'm fully aware I've probably made some very 'noob' errors. However, I'm really stuck when it comes to populating my second drop down list from mySQL, when an option has been selected from a previous drop down list.

I've tried all the forums and have tried example scripts, but each time, I continue to get errors despite trying different examples on the internet. Thus hoping why I wish someone could help me out.

I'm trying to build a small film website, whereby someone can select a film, and then select a date & time and etc. I'm using mySQL to populate the drop down lists but get stuck when I want to populate the second dropdown, with it being dependent on the first option select.

I've tried using AJAX but to no avail. Appreciate I'm probably made some very rookie errors here (possible confusion around variables) but if someone could shed some light on where I'm wrong, I would be really grateful.

Comment: Where are you getting the `$results` variable from at the end of your first code block? Could that be a typo of `$res`?

Answer (score 0):

You have small mistake on getDates.php

```
<?php
    require("Connect.php");

    $name = (!empty($_REQUEST["name"])) ? trim($_REQUEST["name"]) : "");
    if (!empty($name)) {
        $sql = "SELECT Dates FROM Cinema WHERE name = $name";
        try {
            $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
            $stmt->bindValue("tn", trim($name));
            $stmt->execute();
            $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
        } catch (Exception $ex) {
            echo($ex->getMessage());
        }
        if (count($results) > 0) {
        ?>
        <label>Dates: 
            <select name="Dates">
                <?php foreach ($results as $rs) { ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rs["Dates"]; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </label>
        <?php
        } 
    }
?>
```

Try it please and feedback

Comment: thanks for the help - it reads unexpected end of file on the final line - do you have any idea what it is?

Comment: so it looks like the php script for getDates now works. However, I can't get the html to populate the results. I'm quite lost here so appreciate your help with this!

Answer (score 0):

index.php

```
<?php
    require Connect.php;
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Films for Family!!</title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> 
    function Datesforfilms(sel) {
        var name = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].value;
        $("#output1").html("");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getDates.php",
            data: "name=" + name,
            cache: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $("#output1").html(html);;
            }
        });
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="welcome">
        <h1>Films for Family</h1>
    </div>

    <div class="SelectFilm">

        <h3> Step 1: </h3>
        <p> *Select a film*</p>       

        <form name="Filmform" method="get">
            <select name="Select a Film" onChange="Datesforfilms(this);">
                <option value="0">Select a Film</option>
                <?php
                $sql = "SELECT name FROM company";
                $handle = $conn->prepare($sql);
                $handle->execute(array($sql));
                $res = $handle->fetchAll();
                foreach($res as $movie) { ?>
                    <option value="<?=$movie['name']?>"><?=$movie['name']?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
            <div id="output1"></div>    
        </form>    
    </div>     
</body>
</html>
```

getDates.php

```
<?php
require("Connect.php");

$name = (!empty($_POST["name"]) ? trim($_POST["name"]) : "");
if (!empty($name)) {
    $sql = "SELECT Dates FROM Cinema WHERE name = $name";
    try {
        $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
        $stmt->bindValue("tn", trim($name));
        $stmt->execute();
        $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
        echo($ex->getMessage());
    }
    if (count($results) > 0) {
?>
        <label>Dates: 
            <select name="Dates">
                <?php foreach ($results as $rs) { ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $rs["Dates"]; ?>"><?php echo $rs["Dates"]; ?></option>
                <?php } ?>
            </select>
        </label>
    <? } ?>
<? } ?>
```

Comment: By the way you should be wary about SQL injection and script injection - If I ware you I would use MVC such as CakePHP, it will make your life easier

Comment: Thanks Fahed for the help! I've tried running it again but still no luck. It keeps on throwing the following error >> Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'ELF' in 'where clause' << ELF being the name of the film .. do you have any ideas? .. also - on other options, i get this error >>  Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Idiot' at line 1 << do you have any clues? really appreciate all the help

Comment: Why do you have three answers here? You should edit one to include all of the information you want to demonstrate and delete the others.

Comment: 2, make that 3 @JayBlanchard

Comment: @JayBlanchard - again I'm learning something :) - the first answer was edit on his code, the second one was my code

Comment: Just spotted that @RiggsFolly :)